# How to remove all word in a file which does not contain dot using sed

Tags: shell, awk, sed, grep

Here is part of my input file:

```
abc.com may.com xyz li .line 
xyz        
abc efg .com
xyz
aa ab .cool kind.person fruit
yes 
nice
.......
```

I want following Output:

```
abc.com may.com .line       
.com
.cool kind.person
.......
```

I tried using

```
sed '/\./!d' > text.file
```

which gives different output:

```
abc.com may.com xyz li .line
abc efg .com
aa ab .cool kind.person fruit
.......
```

Comment: Where in your input file is `bay.com` ?

Comment: Opps I updated it.

Comment: If `def.` appears in the input then would you want it in the output? How about a lone `.`?

Comment: Yes i want output with all words that has dot in a file. Not sure how to approach this. Should i create array list for each line and remove each array that has dot? Lone . is fine for now. Good to not have it.

Comment: if `sed -E -e 's/(^| +)[^.]+( +|$)/ /g' -e '//d'` does what you want I can make an answer.  Try it here: https://sed.js.org/index.html?gist=de087444fd7309cd86e4233bf6b0a024

Comment: sed -E 's/(^| +)[^.]+( +|$)/ /g' this worked. Could u please explain me in detail how it worked. Thank you so much. I have been learning on my own. This will help me a lot.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah since you replace a non-dot containing word by a space perhaps you should remove it if it starts a line?

Answer (score 0):

With `sed`:

```
sed -E '/\./!d;:a;s/([[:space:]]+|^)[^.[:space:]]+([[:space:]]+|$)/ /;ta'
```

First delete all lines without a dot (like you did yourself). Then search a string formed by the concatenation of:

- a beginning of line or one or more spaces,
- a string of one or more non-space characters that are not a dot,
- a end of line or one or more spaces.

If one is found replace it by a single space and restart (`:a` and `ta`). If you use GNU `sed` you can compact a bit with its `\s` extension:

```
sed -E '/\./!d;:a;s/(\s+|^)[^.[:space:]]+(\s+|$)/ /g;ta'
```

In both cases you will sometimes have lines with leading or trailing spaces, and strings of two or more spaces. If it is a problem you can add some more "cleaning" `sed` commands:

```
sed -E '/\./!d;:a;s/([[:space:]]+|^)[^.[:space:]]+([[:space:]]+|$)/ /g;ta;
  s/(^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$)//;s/[[:space:]]{2,}/ /g'
```

(delete all leading or trailing spaces, plus replace all groups of 2 or more spaces by only one). Or, with GNU `sed`:

```
sed -E '/\./!d;:a;s/(\s+|^)[^.[:space:]]+(\s+|$)/ /g;ta;
  s/(^\s+|\s+$)//;s/\s{2,}/ /g'
```